# Is PositionalEncoding needed for using Transformer models correctly?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer

I am trying to make a model that uses a `Transformer` to see the relationship between several data vectors but the order of the data is not relevant in this case, so I am not using the `PositionalEncoding`.

Since the performance of models using `Transformers` is quite improved with the use of this part do you think that if I remove that part I am breaking the potential of `Transformers` or is it correct to do so?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then you should be fine.  If you aren't trying predict ordered out in particular, it will just look like a bag of words to the Transformer and you won't be using any look-ahead masking or anything so you should be fine.   All the Transformer is doing at that point is creating weighted scores among your input tokens to reveal relationships, unordered in this case.

Comment: Are those output relationships unordered as well if I don't use a PositionalEncoding? @neuroguy123

Comment: I have been thinking about that, and I believe they would be as well.  I would have to research unordered Transformers to know more.  I have tried my own models with and without positional encoding, and they definitely decrease in performance, but that assumes I need order.  I do suspect that it is a more difficult probably space to learn without order regardless.  IF order is important, even if you don't provide a position encoding, it will try to learn one.  Some models, for instance, just add a random variable   after the tokens and you can examine it to show that it becomes positional.